# When I using http comet ,how can I let tomcat send tcp keepalive packet

Tags: java, sockets, tomcat, tcp

I use http comet to make a web chat using this code:

```
public void event(CometEvent event) throws IOException, ServletException {

            HttpServletRequest request = event.getHttpServletRequest();
            HttpServletResponse response = event.getHttpServletResponse();

            String regKey = request.getParameter("rk");
            if (regKey == null) {
                return;
            }

            if (event.getEventType() == CometEvent.EventType.BEGIN) {
                event.setTimeout(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
                System.out.println("Client [" + regKey + "] login...");
                synchronized (connections) {
                    connections.put(regKey, response);
                }
            } else if (event.getEventType() == CometEvent.EventType.ERROR) {
                System.out.println("Client [" + regKey + "] error...");
                synchronized (connections) {
                    connections.remove(regKey);
                }
                event.close();
            } else if (event.getEventType() == CometEvent.EventType.END) {
                System.out.println("Client [" + regKey + "] logout...");
                synchronized (connections) {
                    connections.remove(regKey);
                }
                event.close();
            } else if (event.getEventType() == CometEvent.EventType.READ) {
                System.out.println("Client [" + regKey + "] read...");
                synchronized (connections) {
                    connections.remove(regKey);
                }
                event.close();
            }
        }
```

if the brower or the client close normal i can receive the `CometEvent.EventType.END` event,
but if the client blackout i don't receive any message. I know TCP is waiting for network recovery but i want to process this event so that update online list and other important things(this means I must process this event!!!).
I know the TCP keep-alive can solve this, but tomcat don't send keep-alive packet to client by default, how can I solve it. 
I believe that tomcat can send TCP keep-alive packet, but how to configure tomcat?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it will achieve the behaviour you are looking for but you can enable TCP keep-alive by setting `socket.soKeepAlive="true"` for the NIO HTTP connector in server.xml. If you are using the APR/native HTTP connector there is no configuration option to enable TCK keep-alive. Comet is not supported with the BIO HTTP connector so you'll have to use the NIO HTTP connector if you want to enable TCP keep-alive with Comet.

Comment: Thank you, I am Chinese, so my English is poor. This problem I have been resolved, but when I use tomcat 7 to run a comet web application, I receive 405 in browser, what config file should I change?